# Calculating street network orientation and entropy for individual polygons from a shapefile

Tags: python-3.x, osmnx

I have a shapefile for a city with 150 polygons which represents wards within the city. I would like to calculate street orientation and entropy for all the individual polygons

[image]

I was able to successfully run this code - https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/17-street-network-orientations.ipynb

But i don't know how to replace "Places" with 150 polygons (which has unique id "Ward_No). I've been trying this for weeks but nothing works out. As a start i have used extent of one single polygon and by making use of "graph_from_bbox", entropy was being calculated

```
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import stats

weight_by_length = False

G = ox.graph_from_bbox( 23.17661, 23.16356, 90.21578, 90.22729, network_type='all', simplify=True, clean_periphery=True, retain_all=False)
Gu = ox.add_edge_bearings(ox.get_undirected(G))
fig, ax = ox.plot_orientation(Gu)
print (ox.bearing.orientation_entropy(Gu, num_bins=36, min_length=0, weight=None))

suptitle_font = {
    "family": "DejaVu Sans",
    "fontsize": 30,
    "fontweight": "normal",
    "y": 1,
}
fig.suptitle("Ward 1", **suptitle_font)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
fig.savefig("C:/AC/Snt_GC/street-orientations_3.png", facecolor="w", dpi=200, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close()

#2.9381824546861237
```

Below is the output image

[image]

Since i am very much new to osmnx, not even sure my code is correct.

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "I've been trying this for weeks but nothing works out." We can't guess how to help you if we can't see exactly where the error lies.

Comment: I have edited the question and made it a bit more descriptive.

Comment: I'm still not clear what the question is. You just need a standard Python for loop. Instead of "for place in places" you want to do something like "for polygon in polygons".